# win7 PC can't read CD-Rs?

Tags: windows-7, windows, compact-disc, burning

I have a win7 64-bit system that cannot read burnt CD-R's (even ones it burnt itself!).  How can I troubleshoot and correct this?

Comment: Just replace the hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well replacing the hardware made no difference, which confused the hell out of me.  But on accident, I realized that the drive could write but not read from win7, but it could read within XP Mode!  XP mode was taking over the drives read capability!

So, I shutdown the XP Mode VM, changed its CD drive to none instead of the physical (Because I don't need it in XP Mode usually), and viola!  I can now read CD's again in Win7.

Answer (score 3):

If the discs can be read fine on another PC, try a good DVD lens cleaner and see if that helps. If it doesn't, change the DVD drive.

Comment: So you think there's not way to fix the existing one?

Comment: The drive has [separate read and write lasers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc_drive#Laser_and_optics), so if one is malfunctioning I'm not sure what can be done to fix it. You'd probably need to take it to a hardware repair shop, but given how cheap DVD drives are nowadays I highly recommend you simply get a new one.